# How to add login screen in my email application & login to my email account (windows phone 7)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I created a simple email application for Windows Phone 7, but I need to set-up my email account to send email from my application.

I want to add a login screen in my application so I can set-up my email account and when I put my email user id or password my application should take me to the compose mail screen.

I also want it to remember my user id or password until I logout.

This is my application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace SendingMail
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        EmailAddressChooserTask emailAddresstask;// Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.emailAddresstask = new EmailAddressChooserTask();
            this.emailAddresstask.Completed += new EventHandler<EmailResult>(emailAddresstask_Completed);
        }

        #region Events

        //Open Contact button click
        private void btnOpenContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            emailAddresstask.Show();
        }

        //Email Address Chooser Task Completed
        private void emailAddresstask_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                txtTo.Text = e.Email;
            }
        }

        //Send mail button click
        private void btnMail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EmailComposeTask Myemail_Composetask = new EmailComposeTask();
            Myemail_Composetask.To = txtTo.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Cc = txtCC.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Subject = txtSbj.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Body = txtbd.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Show();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that even attempts to send the email.  If you want assistance you need to attempt this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have mis-understood the how does Email Launcher task works. It does not have any login, or log out options. This Email Launchers task will be used to compose a email on configured email on outlook or other POP, IMAP email application.

Also you will be not able to test on emulator for this. You can only test on the device which has configured at least one email in it.

Thanks,
Kamal.